# hide confidential data for multiple users

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have an user named `eric` which has like user role `Former`.
[image]

I would like the user `Eric` sees only his confidential information but not those of others.

[image]

Would you have any idea how I could make this?

Thank you for your help.

**Edit** Controller **Former**

```
public function index(Request $req)
{   



if ($req->search == "") {
    $formers = Former::paginate(5);

    $formerIdsDown = Cours::where('date_seance', "<=" , Carbon::now())->pluck('fk_former')->toArray();
    return view('admin.formers.index', compact('formers', 'formerIdsDown'));

} else {

    $validated = $req->validate([
        'search' => 'alpha', 
    ]);

    $formers = Former::where('nom', 'LIKE', '%' . $validated['search'] . '%')->paginate(5);
    $formers->appends($req->only('search'));

    $bikeIdsDown = Cours::where('date_seance', "<=" , Carbon::now())->pluck('fk_former')->toArray();

    return view('admin.formers.index', compact('formers', 'formerIdsDown'));
     }

$user = User::when($has_role, function ($query) {
    return $query->where('id', auth()->id()); 
    })
    ->get();

}
```

Comment: If users with role Former should only see their own information why not check that if a user has this role then get only their data?

Answer (score 3):

You could handle this in two ways.

#### Limiting the data from the server

This should be your approach. Here you could add a [condition in your query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses) to know if the user has the restricted role in order to limit the data:

```
# InSomeController.php

$has_role = auth()->user()->hasRole('former'); // checking if the user has the role

$user = User
    ::when($has_role, function ($query) {
        return $query->where('a_column', 'a_value'); // The limitation you want to apply
    })
    ->get(); // executing the query
```

#### Limiting in the view

In case you are using blade templating engine.. you can make use of some [Blade directives](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#if-statements):

```
# in_some_view.blade.php

@if (auth()->user()->hasRole('former'))
    /** Your limited data goes here.. */ 
@else
    /** The default data goes here.. */
@endif
```

---

Obs: In both cases I used the `hasRole('role')` method, replace this with the logic to validate if the user has a given role.

Comment: I would rather use a whitelist approach for roles that are allowed to see the data in the query. If you do it the way you described, adding new roles will create a potential security hole.

Comment: Oh of course @namoshek, this was just to show how the OP can filtered data conditionally.

Comment: I figured so. The OP didn't ask for it, so your answer is fine. Just wanted to address it as suggestion for future readers.

Comment: @user11124425 is just a placeholder for an actual column name that you might want to use.. for example: `->where('id', auth()->id());` or `->where('email', auth()->user()->email);` and so on.. But yeah, you should go for the whitelist approach: Just allow users that has a certain role to see the full list, if not, just return the data anyone can see. But you get the idea.

Comment: @HCK: I have edited my first message... Your code must be in the store () function

Comment: @user11124425 your question was about hidding info relatead to the user role, so it should be placed in the index function.

Comment: @HCK: Ok thank you, I have tried, but nothing happening, the code is always the same...                                                                               `$has_role = auth()->user()->hasRole('former'); 

        $user = User::when($has_role, function ($query) {
        return $query->where('email', auth()->user()->email);
        })
        ->get();`